# How do I returned a TYPED result?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I would like to define `Sorted` to be of type `ErrorProviderMessageCollection`, which is what `unsortedCollection` is defined as.

```
Dim Sorted As ErrorProviderMessageCollection = From item In unsortedCollection 
                                               Order By item.Control.TabIndex
```

How do I do this?

```
Public Class ErrorProviderMessage Implements IComparable(Of ErrorProviderMessage)

    Private _Message As String
    Private _Control As Control

    Public Sub New(ByVal message As String, ByVal control As Control)
        _Message = message
        _Control = control
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Message() As String
        Get
            Return _Message
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Control() As Control
        Get
            Return _Control
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As ErrorProviderMessage) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of ErrorProviderMessage).CompareTo
        Return Me.Control.TabIndex.CompareTo(other.Control.TabIndex)
    End Function

End Class

Public Class ErrorProviderMessageCollection

    Inherits System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of ErrorProviderMessage)

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use Lambda and an appropriate extension method to deal with the casting e.g:

```
var Sorted = unsortedCollection.OrderBy(i=>i.Control.TabIndex).ToSortedErrorProviderMessageCollection();
```

and the extension method...

```
public static class ErrorProviderMessageCollectionHelper
{
    public static ErrorProviderMessageCollection ToSortedErrorProviderMessageCollection <T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : ErrorProviderMessage 
    {
        var orderedCollection = new ErrorProviderMessageCollection();
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            orderedCollection.Add(item);
        }
        return orderedCollection;
    }
}
```

I'm not up on VB.NET so provide the code example in C#.

Comment: I changed it to this but it returns "Nothing": Dim Sorted As ErrorProviderMessageCollection = TryCast(unsortedCollection.OrderBy(Function(i) i.Control.TabIndex), ErrorProviderMessageCollection)

Comment: Are you able to post the code for ErrorProviderMessageCollection?

Comment: OK you will either need to use an extension method/ienumerable helper (see previous post to get the idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100851/how-do-you-cast-an-ienumerablet-or-iqueryablet-to-an-entitysett) or resort to a foreach statement e.g. foreach (var p in unsortedCollection.OrderBy(i => i.Control.TabIndex)) { Sorted.Add(p); }

Comment: I'll give it a try and use it if nothing better comes up, but my first reatuion is that I shouldn't have to recreate the collection myself.

Comment: OK well let me know how you get on. It appears quite a few other people on here have gone down the extension method path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121938/how-do-i-convert-ienumerable-to-a-custom-type-in-c

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to do it like this:

```
Dim Sorted As ErrorProviderMessageCollection = 
    New ErrorProviderMessageCollection(From item In unsortedCollection 
                                       Order By item.Control.TabIndex)
```

For this to work `ErrorProviderMessageCollection` needs a constructor that takes a parameter of type `IEnumerable(Of TypeOfItem)`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the approved answer, this worked. A workinge example shown here:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim MyCollection As New ErrorProviderMessageCollection


        If txtLastName.Text.Trim = "" Then
            MyCollection.Add(New ErrorProviderMessage("Last Name required", txtLastName, txtLastName.TabIndex))
        End If

        If txtFirstName.Text.Trim = "" Then
            MyCollection.Add(New ErrorProviderMessage("First Name required", txtFirstName, txtFirstName.TabIndex))
        End If

        Dim Sorted As ErrorProviderMessageCollection = New ErrorProviderMessageCollection(From item In MyCollection Order By item.Control.TabIndex)

        For Each ErrorProviderMessage As ErrorProviderMessage In Sorted
            MessageBox.Show(ErrorProviderMessage.Message & " " & ErrorProviderMessage.Control.TabIndex & " " & ErrorProviderMessage.Control.Name)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

End Class


Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ErrorProviderMessage

    Private _Message As String
    Private _Control As Control
    Private _TabIndex As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal message As String, ByVal control As Control, ByVal tabIndex As Integer)
        _Message = message
        _Control = control
        _TabIndex = tabIndex
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Message() As String
        Get
            Return _Message
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Control() As Control
        Get
            Return _Control
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Tabindex() As Integer
        Get
            Return _TabIndex
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _TabIndex = value
        End Set
    End Property


End Class


Public Class ErrorProviderMessageCollection

    Inherits System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of ErrorProviderMessage)

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of ErrorProviderMessage))

        Dim orderedCollection = New ErrorProviderMessageCollection()

        For Each Item As ErrorProviderMessage In source
            Me.Add(Item)
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```